# Want to make bot only send messages to a specific person

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Alright so I made an embed for my discord bot, but I only want it to message a specific person. What should I add to make it do that?

Here is my code:

```
    if ( msg.content === "WhoseMyWaifu"){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        msg.reply(    
            embed.setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png'),
            embed.setColor('RANDOM'),
            embed.setFooter(msg.author.username),
            );
    }  

})
```

Comment: Do you mean a DM? If so, then all you need is to grab the `user` object, and then append the `send` method. Link for more info: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=send

Answer (score 0):

you can check author's ID

```js
if (msg.content === "WhoseMyWaifu" && msg.author.id === "SOME_USER_ID"){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        msg.reply(    
            embed.setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png'),
            embed.setColor('RANDOM'),
            embed.setFooter(msg.author.username),
            );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

or if you want more than one person to do it

```js
const user = ["id1","id2",....]
if (msg.content === "WhoseMyWaifu" && user.includes(message.author.id)){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        msg.reply(    
            embed.setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png'),
            embed.setColor('RANDOM'),
            embed.setFooter(msg.author.username),
            );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :)

```
const users = ["user1", "user2"] // add anyones ID her
if (msg.content == "WhoseMyWaifu" || users.includes(msg.author.id)) {
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed
msg.reply(
            embed.setImage('https://toppng.com/public/uploads/thumbnail/load-68-more-imagesgrid-view-me-dio-11563057753kl6hlthvsz.png'),
            embed.setColor('RANDOM'),
            embed.setFooter(msg.author.username),
);
}
```